# BiDirectional Dijkstras and A* Algorithms

Tags: algorithm, graph, hadoop, mapreduce, graph-algorithm

I wanted to implement BiDirectional Djikstras and A* algorithms in MapReduce. 
I have already finished implementing Djikstras in MapReduce.
I was wondering if anyone has came across the implementations for the same?

Comment: What exactly are you having in mind? Please consider that (AFAIK) bi-directional search fails when it comes to *weighted graph*.

Comment: This was for implementation of project.. analysis of road networks data..

Answer (score 3):

Few links to help out:

- [A Hadoop MapReduce Solution to Dijkstra’s Algorithm](http://famousphil.com/blog/2011/06/a-hadoop-mapreduce-solution-to-dijkstra%E2%80%99s-algorithm/)
- [Iterative MapReduce and Counters](http://hadooptutorial.wikispaces.com/Iterative+MapReduce+and+Counters)

You could also take a look at [Apache Giraph](http://incubator.apache.org/giraph/) for doing large-scale graph processing tasks.

- [Giraph Shortest Paths Example](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/GIRAPH/Shortest+Paths+Example)

Comment: Also at Apache Hama http://hama.apache.org/hama_graph_tutorial.html which is faster.